# Does a change in a component refresh the whole page or just that component which was changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so I am new to React. Loving it so far. However, I am having a basic question which doesn't have a clear answer right now.

So, I am learning how to lift the state of a component.
So here's a reproducible example.

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import {Component} from "react";

// import AppFooter from "./AppFooter";
import AppContent from "./AppContent";
import AppHeader from "./AppHeader";

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min'
import './index.css'

class App extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handlePostChange = this.handlePostChange.bind(this)
        this.state = {
            "posts": []
        }
    }

    handlePostChange = (posts) => {
        this.setState({
            posts: posts
        })
    }

    render() {
        const headerProps = {
            title: "Hi Keshav. This is REACT.",
            subject: "My Subject is Krishna.",
            favouriteColor: "blue"
        }
        return (
            <div className="app">
                <div>
                    <AppHeader {...headerProps} posts={this.state.posts} handlePostChange={this.handlePostChange}/>
                    <AppContent handlePostChange={this.handlePostChange}/>
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

I am trying to lift the state of posts which is changed in AppContent to AppHeader.
Here's my AppContent.js and AppHeader.js

```
// AppContent.js
import React, {Component} from "react";

export default class AppContent extends Component{

    state = {
        posts: []
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props); // constructor
        this.handlePostChange = this.handlePostChange.bind(this)
    }

    handlePostChange = (posts) => {
        this.props.handlePostChange(posts)
    }

    fetchList = () => {
        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
            .then((response) =>
                response.json()
            )
            .then(json => {
                // let posts = document.getElementById("post-list")
                this.setState({
                    posts: json
                })
                this.handlePostChange(json)
            })
    }
    clickedAnchor = (id) => {
        console.log(`Clicked ${id}`)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>This is the app content.</p>
                <button onClick={this.fetchList} className="btn btn-outline-primary">Click</button>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <hr/>
                <ul>
                    {this.state.posts.map((item) => {
                        return (
                            <li id={item.id}>
                                <a href="#!" onClick={() => this.clickedAnchor(item.id)}>{item.title}</a>
                            </li>
                        )
                    })}
                </ul>
                <hr/>
                <p>There are {this.state.posts.length} entries in the posts.</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

```
// AppHeader.js
import React, {Component, Fragment} from "react";

export default class AppHeader extends Component{

    constructor(props) {
        super(props); // constructor
        this.handlePostChange=this.handlePostChange.bind(this)
    }

    handlePostChange = (posts) => {
        this.props.handlePostChange(posts)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <div>
                    <p>There are {this.props.posts.length} posts.</p>
                    <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
                </div>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

So here's the main question. As we see, that I am calling the dummy posts api and trying to show the titles of the json object list returned by it.

The posts state is actually updated in AppContent and is shared to AppHeader by lifting it to the common ancestor index.js

However, here's what I have observed.
When I keep this code running using `npm start` I see that anytime I make a change in any place, it refreshes. I was under the impression that it renders the whole page running on localhost:3000.

Say here's my current situation on the web page:
[image: Browser screen when the data is fetched.]

Now, say I make a change in just AppContent.js, then here's how it looks then:
[image: After change in only AppContent]

In here, we see that it's still showing 100 posts in case of AppHeader. Is this expected that react only reloads the component and not the whole page. When I refresh the whole page, it shows 0 posts and 0 posts in both the places. Now have I made a mistake in writing the code ? If yes, how do I fix this ?

Thank you.
In case the question is not clear please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

> In here, we see that it's still showing 100 posts in case of AppHeader. Is this expected that react only reloads the component and not the whole page.

It's not React, per se, that's doing that. It's whatever you're using to do hot module reloading (probably a bundler of some kind, like Webpack or Vite or Rollup or Parcel or...). This is a very handy feature, but yes, it can cause this kind of confusion.

> Now have I made a mistake in writing the code ?

One moderately-signficant one, a relatively minor but important one, and a couple of trivial ones:

1. `posts` should **either** be state in `App` or `AppContent` but not both of them. If it's state in both of them, they can get out of sync — as indeed you've seen with the hot module reloading thing. If you want `posts` to be held in `App`, fetch it there and provide it to `AppContent` as a property. (Alternatively you could remove it from `App` and just have it in `AppContent`, but then you couldn't show the total number of posts in `App`.)
2. When you're rendering the array of posts, you need to have a [key](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper) on each of the `li` items so that React can manage the DOM nodes efficiently and correctly.
3. There's no need to wrap a `Fragment` around a single element as you are in `AppHeader`.
4. If you make `handlePostChange` an arrow function assigned to a property, there's no reason to `bind` it in the constructor. (I would make it a method instead, and keep the `bind` call, but others like to use an arrow function and not `bind`.)
5. There's no reason for the wrapper `handlePostChange` functions that just turn around and call `this.props.handlePostChange`; just use the function you're given.
6. Two issues with your `fetch` call:

   - You're not checking for HTTP success before calling `json`. This is a footgun in the `fetch` API I describe [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) on my very old anemic blog. Check `response.ok` before calling `response.json`.
   - You're ignoring errors, but should report them (via a `.catch` handler).

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer. In point 1, posts is getting changed in AppContent and I want to share it with AppHeader. For that based on what I read, I should create that variable as a state In the nearest common ancestor right ? Which in this case is App, so is there a problem